# How to XOR a String using a byte array as key?

Tags: java, android, encryption, cryptography, xor

I am trying to encode a String using XOR encryption and use a `byte array` as key:

```
String encodedString = myString XOR myKey
```

I don't have too much experience with cryptography so I haven't found a way to achieve this.

As an update of this question I found out that the `myKey` is also a String and has the same length as `myString`

Comment: Is the key the same size as the string? I assume not. Also, XOR is not encryption.

Comment: Please do **not** change the question after you've asked it. I could alter my answer in this case, but I really should not have to. XOR of two strings rather than a string and a byte array is something different. The word "key" is now missing entirely from your question... rolling back to previous edit. Enhancing your question is always allowed, but changing the semantics of it is not.

Comment: Not sure what you tried to do, but with the last rollback you just removed the [tag:xor] tag (?) If you want you could add on to the end of the question what to do if the key is a string; I've put it in my answer already after all.

Comment: @MaartenBodewes I really apreciate all your comments to help me improve. Actually I am still trying to undersatand what I should do to solve this

Comment: public static byte[] xorWithKey(byte[] a, byte[] key) {
        byte[] out = new byte[a.length];
        for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
            out[i] = (byte) (a[i] ^ key[i]);
        }
        return out;
    } this is what I tried

Comment: Still not sure if this is correct

Comment: Looks fine to me on first glance. You can always try some known values, like a XOR of bytes `0x00`, `0xC3`, `0x3C`, `0xFF` and the like.  Since Java uh, someversion, you can even specify the bytes as `0b0011_1100` instead of `0x3C`. Sometimes you'll have to cast to `(byte)` if the value is too large to fit in a *signed* byte value though.

Answer (score 2):

```
String encodedString = myString XOR myKey
```

This is not correct. A string in Java may have any encoding. An encoding of a string is a representations using a specific character encoding *in bytes*, i.e. a byte array.

So you would do:

```
byte[] encodedString = myString.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
```

to retrieve the bytes.

Then you can iterate over the bytes of the `encodedString` using an index. You would get the byte at the same location in the binary key and XOR the two bytes together.  The result can be put in a new array of the same size as `encodedString`. Note that Java is slightly strange in that you may require a cast back to a byte value to do so, i.e. `result[i] = (byte) xorResult`

Commonly, you will have to reset the index within the key to zero again if you run out of bytes in the key. If that happens, your encryption scheme will become vulnerable to attack, as a one-time-pad (OTP) is secure, but XOR cipher certainly is not.

After decryption, which is the same operation as encryption, you can get your string back using:

```
String myString = new String(encodedString, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
```

---

Obviously you would have to do the same for the key if that is a string. Note however that, even if the key is well distributed over the *printable* characters, the *bit values* are likely *not* well distributed. In other words, a string as a XOR key leaves you vulnerable to crypto analysis, frequency analysis on the bits and bytes in particular.

---

The XOR will result in randomized bytes, so you may need to base 64 encode (after encryption) / decode (before decryption) to get a ciphertext string rather than a byte array.

---

I've deliberately left out the code to do this as this is a practice assignment, have fun implementing it!

Comment: So basically what I should do is myString.getBytes(); and then start iterating with the bytes that myKey contains?

Comment: Yes, that's it. However, your index is best from 0 to the size of the plaintext (in bytes) rather than the key - the plaintext indicates how many bytes need to be encrypted, after all.

Answer (score 1):

Finally got it!

Hope this is usefull for someone else.

This is what worked for me (XOR within 2 Strings):

```
public static String xorHex(String a, String b) {
    // TODO: Validation
    char[] chars = new char[a.length()];
    for (int i = 0; i < chars.length; i++) {
        chars[i] = toHex(fromHex(a.charAt(i)) ^ fromHex(b.charAt(i)));
    }
    return new String(chars);
}


private static int fromHex(char c) {
    if (c >= '0' && c <= '9') {
        return c - '0';
    }
    if (c >= 'A' && c <= 'F') {
        return c - 'A' + 10;
    }
    if (c >= 'a' && c <= 'f') {
        return c - 'a' + 10;
    }
    throw new IllegalArgumentException();
}

private static char toHex(int nybble) {
    if (nybble < 0 || nybble > 15) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException();
    }
    return "0123456789ABCDEF".charAt(nybble);
}
```